# Eliminate duplicate for a column value in a Dataframe - the column holds multiple URL's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so i have a column called "URL's" in my DataFrame Pd1

```
        URL

row 1 : url1,url1,url2
row 2 : url2,url2,url3
```

output :

```
        URL
row 1 : url1,url2
row 2 : url2,url3
```

Comment: What code have you tried, also I assume you are using pandas?

Comment: Is the `URL` column just a string, or does it contain a list?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['URL'] = df.URL.str.split(':').apply(lambda x: [x[0],','.join(sorted(set(x[1].split(','))))]).apply(' : '.join)
```

---

```
                  URL
0  row 1  : url1,url2
1  row 2  : url2,url3
```

if **data**

```
              URL
0  url1,url1,url2
1  url2,url2,url3
```

then

```
df['URL'] = df.URL.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(set(x))))
##print(df)

        URL
0  url1,url2
1  url2,url3
```

Comment: Nice job, but I have a feeling that "row1: " and "row 2:" are not part of `URL` column, but the way he wrote the index of the df.

Comment: ahh!! i went with `so i have a column called "URL's" in my DataFrame Pd1`, if OP changes then i'll change accodingly

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your column contains only URL list.

One of possible solutions is to:

- apply a function to *URL* column, containing the following steps:

  - split the source string on each comma (tre result is a list of
    fragments),
  - create a set from this list (thus eleminating repetitions),
  - join keys from this set, using a comma,
- save the result back into the source column.

Something like:

```
df.URL = df.URL.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(re.split(',', x))))
```

As this code uses *re* module, you have to *import re* before.

Answer (score 0):

split and apply set

```py
d = {"url": ["url1,url1,url2",
"url2,url2,url3"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.url.str.split(",").apply(set)
```